# Load content in multiple elements via url and dynamic php?

Tags: php, html, dynamic

I want to use a page url ala www.site.com/index.php?content=page3 and have two or three sections of the loaded page have different content depending on the content= string in the URL? This would also obviously include the page title.

Comment: And what is your question? "Write codes for me"?

Comment: You have to stop thinking of `index.php` === `a web page`. That does not make sense in modern web technology. The _full_ URL including those arguments identifies "a page" (or an object), that is what you are interested in. What _content_ you place inside that page is completely up to you. You have the argument as value available inside a variable on the server side, so generate and output the content you want reacting on that.

Comment: @u_mulder that's not a helpful comment at all. Some suggestions as to what type of markup to use would have been helpful.

Comment: If you forgot rules of the site - please check [ask].